# When can linear functionals be random variables?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, P)$ be a probability space and let $V = L^1(\Omega, \mathscr F, P)$, i.e. $V$ is the set of all $\mathscr F$-measurable functions $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ (which we call random variables) such that $E|X| < \infty$. We know that $V$ is a Banach space with $||X|| = E|X|$.

Now let $V^*$ be the dual space of $V$ so that $\phi \in V^*$ is a linear functional mapping random variables from $V$ into $\mathbb R$.

My question: what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $\phi$ to be a random variable in its own right?

The codomain of $\phi$ is $\mathbb R$, so all we need is for it to be measurable, but here's where I'm stuck. I know that generally continuity and especially linearity are sufficient for measurability, but measurability with respect to what? What is the $\sigma$-algebra over $V$ that we are considering?

Using the norm on $V$ we have that it's a metric space too, so we've got open sets, so could we consider the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all of these open sets in an analogy to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

**Update**

I'll try to be more precise about what I'm looking for. Suppose we have $\Omega = \{w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ and $\mathscr F = 2^\Omega$. Then every function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is both measurable and integrable so $V = \mathbb R^n$ and $\dim V^* = n$ too. Now for $\phi \in V^*$ we have $\phi: V \to \mathbb R$ so if $\phi$ is to be a random variable we need a $\sigma$-algebra over $V$. So in this case we could consider the measurable space $(\mathbb R^n, \mathcal B^n)$ where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, so we need $\phi : V \to \mathbb R$ to be measruable w.r.t. $\mathcal B^n$, and since $\phi$ is continuous this is true. Thus every linear functional $\phi \in V^*$ is a $\mathcal B^n$-measurable function from $V$ to $\mathbb R$, so by definiton these are random variables and once we have a measure it makes sense to talk about $E(\phi)$ and $Var(\phi)$.

My question is about the general case. If $V$ is infinite dimensional, we now need $\phi$ to be measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra over an infinite dimensional space and I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: Isn't $V^*$ identifiable with $L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$?

Comment: @kimchilover i _think_ so? but even so, how does that help?

Comment: I don't understand the soul of your question.  Are you happy with $L^1([0,1],\mathcal B, \mu)^* = L^\infty([0,1],\mathcal B,\mu)$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure?  The elements of $L^\infty$ are born measurable, and turn out to be the set of continuous linear functions on $L^1$.

Comment: @kimchilover that might be exactly what I'm looking for! I'm new to functional analysis and i read something about how linear functionals of random variables can be random variables in their own right, but to me that means we need a $\sigma$-algebra that they're measurable with respect to and i couldn't think of what that could be since this $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of sets of random variables so we need a way to measure sets of random variables, which is a very new concept to me. Are you saying that my $V^*$ is $L^\infty$ so thereby we get measurability?